# List available Wi-Fi networks and bridges even though they share the same SSID

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-bridge

Using the `netsh wlan show networks mode=bssid` command you can list the currently visible Wi-Fi networks/bridges within signal range. However per my understanding this will just show the networks like if you were to open the regular network menu from the taskbar.

Where I work we have dozens of bridges/access points scattered around the building, **where all share the same SSID**. I would like to get a list of the ones within signal range and be able to check the signal quality and MAC address of them.

Is this possible, or is the `netsh wlan show networks mode=bssid` command already doing that? (I'm asking the latter because I am currently in no ability to test it, and I need this to continue with what I'm working on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,that's what you get with mode=bssid.

Here's an example round me at the moment

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the networks/access points in your picture do not have the same SSID, where all the ones around me does. The problem that I'm concerned about (if I've properly understood how the command works) would be that it might only show one of them because the rest have the exact same SSID.

Comment: @VisualVincent: **Look carefully.** _Two_ out of three items in that list – `VM9311658` and `BTWifi-X` – have two APs (distinct BSSIDs) with the same ESSID.

Comment: Ooh! I completely missed that! I'll actually be able to verify it in about 45 minutes, so hang in there.